# Are there any user interface prototyping tools for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, user-interface, prototyping

I am looking into designing new features for Eclipse-based programming tools, from the requirements/ideas perspective. To really do this quickly, I would like to sketch UI elements without having to code things -- my concern is with the concepts and ideas right now, not the possible later realization.  Are there any such graphical sketching tools for Eclipse?

(on a side note, I should also note that I find Eclipse a better idea every day, in the way that you can combine partial systems from very many different sources into a single environment. It really is the future of IDEs, especially for embedded systems.  It used to pretty horrible pre-Eclipse-3.0, but now it does seem to work)

Answer (score 3):

[WireframeSketcher](http://wireframesketcher.com) is a tool that helps quickly create wireframes, mockups and prototypes for desktop, web and mobile applications. It comes both as a **standalone** version and as a **plug-in** for Eclipse IDEs. It has some distinctive features like storyboards, components, linking and vector PDF export. Among supported IDEs are are Aptana, Flash Builder, Zend Studio and Rational Application Developer.

[image: Sample WireframeSketcher mockup]
<sub>(source: [wireframesketcher.com](http://wireframesketcher.com/samples/Website.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, NetBeans is known for having a really good GUI editor (Matisse), but I realize that you weren't asking about NetBeans :)

Comment: The problem I had with that thing is that the code is unmaintainable if you have people *not* usin Netbeans on your project. I don't know how well you can cope wit it *if* using Netbeans, but just having the code without a designer is a nightmare to work with. But I guess that Java's layout managers have been a really bad idea when it comes to visual design tools (from my experience so far at least).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the [Visual Editor Project](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/WebContent/main.php) before, but in the past it crashed my instance of Eclipse, and I haven't visited it since.

[Jigloo](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/os-dw-os-eclipse-jigloo.html) is a new one that I'd like to try out soon.

Comment: Thanks, too bad that VEP seems to be an abandoned project that is not even on Europa yet.  It sounded like what I needed.

Comment: there is a community based fork of this project now: http://sourceforge.net/projects/visualeditor/

Answer (score 0):

This is really specific to Eclipse: it is the platform of choice for general IDEs today, and I am looking to sketch out extensions to it.  The target programming language is more likely to be raw assembler and C than anything else -- OS, driver, system-level debug.